# Any Open Source projects that has Selenium 2.0 tests?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting to use Selenium for UI testing and was wondering if there were any open source projects with decent tests that I can use for learning about how to design the Selenium tests.

Any other resources about designing the UI tests would also be appreciated.

I've read the documentation on the Selenium website which is a good start but I'm hoping to find some info/examples of how to make sure your numerous tests are maintainable in the future.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

[GWT Mobile Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) appears to be using Selenium. I had read that jQuery was using it, but I can't see any evidence of them using it in there source code repository.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558617/a-good-working-example-of-selenium2-and-webdriver/5578149#5578149) helpful.

**Update:**

[Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) has some tests that can be found [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#wBZsFl6bRv8/trunk/tests/com/google/caja/plugin/BrowserTestCase.java&q=import%20org.openqa.selenium%20google-caja&type=cs)

A search on [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=import%20org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver) may also help track down examples of usage.

Comment: I had a look at GWT Mobile Web Toolkit but couldn't find any Selenium/WebDriver tests. Any ideas if they are on the code.google project site?

Comment: Although I can see Selenium in their source repo it would appear that the tests are stored elsewhere. :-(

Comment: The google code search links are broken

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the guys over at Atlassian are using it for Jira and some of there other projects:

- [Part 1](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/09/smarter_acceptance_testing_with_jira_page_objects_part_one/)
- [Part 2](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/09/smarter_acceptance_testing_with_jira_page_objects_part_two/)
- [Part 3](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/09/smarter_acceptance_testing_jira_page_objects_part_3/)

part 3 has links to the projects that they have been working on.