# Generics with Cucumber-jvm and Page Objects don't work

Tags: java, generics, webdriver, cucumber, pageobjects

Please, help:
I am using cucumber-jvm+WebDriver+jUnit+maven with Page Object pattern for Automation Testing.

I want to have a method which can return multiple types of objects. (different expected pages).
In my past i used Generics to implement it with clear java+Webdriver.
In [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371699/how-to-implement-webdriver-pageobject-methods-that-can-return-different-pageobje) there is a good explanation of this.

But now i want to inplement it with cucumber.

My Project Structure looks next way:

**Driver base class:**

```
public class DriverBase {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Navigator Class for interacting between page objects:**

```
public class Navigator {
    DriverBase base;
    WebDriver driver;

    public NavigationActions(DriverBase base) {
        this.base = base;
        this.driver = base.driver;
    }

    public FirstPage openFirstPage(){
    driver.get("someUrl");
    return new FirstPage(base);
    } 
}
```

**Page objects classes:**

```
public class FirstPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    DriverBase base;
    //...
    //Elements locators...
    //Some methods...
    //...
        public FirstPage(DriverBase base) {
            this.base = base;
            this.driver = base.driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

     public <T> T openSecondOrThirdPage(String secondPgUrl, Class<T> expectedPage) {
     driver.get("secondPgUrl");
     return PageFactory.initElements(driver, expectedPage);
}
```

**and**

```
public class SecondPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    DriverBase base;
    //...
    //Elements locators...
    //Some methods...
    //...
        public SecondPage(DriverBase base) {
            this.base = base;
            this.driver = base.driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }
}
```

**My StepsDefinition class:**

```
public class MyTestStepsDefs {
    DriverBase base;
    Navigator navigator;

@Given("^bla-bla$"){
    public void go_from_first_to_second_page() {
    navigator.openFirstPage().openSecondOrThirdPage("http://urlOfMyPage.com", SecondPage.class); 
}
@When("^blu-blu$")
    public void login_with_selected_role() {
System.out.println("Some log");
}
@Then("^blo-blo$")
    public void check_links_available(List<String> availableLinks) {
System.out.println("Some log");
}
```

So, when i run this cucumber test - on openSecondOrThirdPage method error appears:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: myprjct.pages.SecondPage
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:66)
    at myprjct.pages.FirstPage.openSecondOrThirdPage(FirstPage.java:31)
    .......
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: myprjct.pages.SecondPage
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:66)
    ........
```

Please, suggest me, what i am doind wrong?

Comment: As I can see method is declared to accept arguments of type string and generic class `openSecondOrThirdPage(String secondPgUrl, Class<T> expectedPage)` but I assume you pass wrong arguments `openSecondOrThirdPage(driver, SecondPage.class)` because I bet your `driver` is an instance of WebDriver class. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, You was right. - i have fixed it - it was just a mistake when i were writing this example for post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that your Page Object does not have a constructor that matches one of these criteria:

- Takes "WebDriver" as its sole argument (*public SomePage(WebDriver driver)*).
- Default constructor.

Your constructor is something like *public SecondPage(DriverBase base)* instead, and given that if you write a constructor with arguments for your class then Java does not generate a default constructor, that might be the problem. PageFactory cannot instantiate your page object because it cannot find a suitable constructor.

You can find more information about the PageFactory here.
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend! You pushed me in right direction. I'v made my page objects with WebDriver argument only and also i have used SharedDriver in my StepsDef class. And now it works fine. Thanks a lot.