# Java/Selenium WebDriver: How to get user input and insert it in to a text field?

Tags: java, eclipse, input, selenium-webdriver, java.util.scanner

At the moment in Eclipse, I have the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).clear();
System.out.println("Username: ");
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String input1 = scan1.nextLine();
System.out.println(input1);
```

and was just wondering, instead of it simply returning the user's input in to the console, is there a way to get it to insert it in to the text field. I want to insert it into a field which has the name *LoginText1*. This is for website testing with Selenium WebDriver.
I am new to Java and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did either of the answers solve your problem? If so, mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the edits on your question, I'm afraid I can only link you to Selenium's online documentation:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: did you declare the textfield?

Comment: If you mean what you just changed, then no. I have done exactlty what you wrote:   
`LoginText1 = new JTextField(20);    
LoginText1.setText(input1);`  
But I still get the same error, but now in both places.

Comment: @D.Shah You need to really read into the basics of Java before jumping into Gui. Grab a book and start from the beginning.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I don't appear to have the time, and I think this is one of the only things I am having a problem with now. Also, I tried what you said, I didn't get the error, but it still doesn't enter the text in to the field.  
_Also, what would I need the JFrame for?_

Comment: I added the JFrame and the rest, but when I run it, it simply gives me a Java Pop-up with the username I entered. It still doesn't enter the username in to the field.

Comment: The "Pop-up" is actually a jFrame that contains the jTextField with the username. I thought thats what you wanted?

Comment: No, I needed the text the user inputs to be inserted in to the text field.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between what should be happening and what actually happens?

Comment: _What is happening_: When I run it, in the Console it asks me for the username. After I enter it, there is a java pop-up which has the user input written in, and the header of what I put in "Your JFrame".  
_What I need_: For it to ask the user for the username or an input, and then after the user has input something, it inserts that in to the username text-field on the website.

Comment: @D.Shah That small edit you did not long ago changes the question entirely... You aren't asking how to fill in a textfield in java, you are asking how to fill in a textfield on a website via selenium-webdriver. You should have stated this from the beginning

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  
So, would all the JFrame stuff be irrelevant to this or still be useful?

Comment: No. Go look at my edited answer. I strongly suggest before going further with web-automation that you sit down and learn some basic java.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply do something like this

```
LoginText1.setText(input1);
```

I suggest looking into JTextField documentation and you would have quickly found examples and solutions to your problem.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

I also suggest looking into variable naming conventions (LoginText1 should start with a lowercase).

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

**EDIT**

After seeing your most recent edit, you are wanting to fill in a form from a website using selenium webdriver. A post at StackOverflow shows just that using the `sendKeys()` method.

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558617/a-good-working-example-of-selenium2-and-webdriver)

Comment: I added that, and also added `import java.awt.TextField;` but I get the error _Logintext1 cannot be resolved_. Also, I would change the name of the field if I could, but I don't have that sort of access. I am just supposed to make automated testing using Selenium for as many browsers as possible.

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario user is passing the password manually through console.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String password;   
                System.out.println("Please Enter the user password :: ");
                password= br.readLine();  
                driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable `index` wherever it is required.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("Index of the sheet: ");
int index = br.read();
```