# Is there any dummy project test cases for webdrive selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium WebDrive. Is there any dummy projects or testcases that could help me start learning? Could you please suggest some starting points?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a dummy class as shown below..

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestExample {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testExample() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

And just make sure you have the Selenium maven repo in your pom with junit.

Comment: The above example is really nothing more that you would already find by just reading the Selenium documentation.

Comment: I think that's actually where I got it originally, but it was in my project at the time and it met OP's description.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following

[Getting Started Guide](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)

[documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

[more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558617/a-good-working-example-of-selenium2-and-webdriver)